# self healing of linux servers

Tags: linux

I have two identical servers. one is main server which responds to the clients request. Other server will constantly check whether main server in up or not. If main server is down then this identical server should act as main server automatically. Now my question is, is there any process to make my second server up when my main server is down???

Thank you...

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Linux-HA](http://linux-ha.org).

Answer (score 3):

If what you need is theoretical explanation then you should be reading about [High Availability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability). If what you need is specific information for your environment then you should provide us with more data about your server's configuration and environment.